# Postgresql function, do different JOIN conditionally

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgresql 12. In a function returning a SELECT result of table A and B, when the function input Boolean parameter is true, do

```
select * from A INNER join B on A.id = B.id;
```

when the parameter is false, do

```
select * from A LEFT join B on A.id = B.id;
```

checked case-when-end but it doesn't work in "where". Is there any way to achieve this without writing two separate SELECT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` in which the non-nullable column of right table is forced to be NOT NULL in the result is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=53333a1c22a395b4b65ad10ae8d80ef7)

```
SELECT *
  FROM A LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE NOT param         -- allow LEFT JOIN behavior
    OR B.id IS NOT NULL  -- force INNER JOIN behavior
;
```

**Test 1:**

```
WITH A (id) AS (
         VALUES (1), (2), (3)
     )
   , B (id) AS (
         VALUES (1),      (3)
     )
   , args (isInner) AS (
         SELECT true
     )
SELECT *
  FROM A LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE (SELECT NOT isInner FROM args)
    OR B.id IS NOT NULL
;
```

**Result (INNER JOIN):**

[image]

**Test 2:**

```
WITH A (id) AS (
         VALUES (1), (2), (3)
     )
   , B (id) AS (
         VALUES (1),      (3)
     )
   , args (isInner) AS (
         SELECT false
     )
SELECT *
  FROM A LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE (SELECT NOT isInner FROM args)
    OR B.id IS NOT NULL
;
```

**Result (LEFT JOIN):**

[image]

Comment: Clever approach!

Comment: Wonderful solution!